# Appengine skeleton not running

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, target

I'm trying to run the google appengine project skeleton using Maven build and displays the error

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: The application directory does not exist : C:\Bruna\ambiente\workspace\request-food\target/request-food-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

the directory after the target is with a backslash "/" I'm using windows how do I change this bar for "\"

pom.xml

target\${project.artifactId}-${project.version}\WEB-INF\classes 
        
            
                org.apache.maven.plugins
                maven-war-plugin
                2.3
                
                    true
                    
                        
                            ${basedir}\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF
                            true
                            WEB-INF

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about the backslash. It's a red herring.

The problem is that you are trying to execute the devserver from the top-level, whereas you should be executing it from the -ear directory. Easiest way to do this is

```
mvn -pl yourartifactid-ear appengine:devserver
```

Comment: I make this mistake a lot and so I think @dxi is probably right that @Gleidosn was probably needed to change to the ear directory before launching `mvn appengine:devserver`